# Exception in thread "OkHttp Dispatcher" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gson.JsonParser.parseString(Ljava/lang/String;)

Tags: spring-boot, splunk

I am using splunk java logging library and application is able to send logs to splunk server. But when we are starting application so we see below logs and those are very annoying because it gets printed again and again.

```
Exception in thread "OkHttp Dispatcher" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gson.JsonParser.parseString(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/google/gson/JsonElement;
    at com.splunk.logging.HttpEventCollectorErrorHandler$ServerErrorException.<init>(HttpEventCollectorErrorHandler.java:56)
    at com.splunk.logging.HttpEventCollectorSender$3.completed(HttpEventCollectorSender.java:308)
    at com.splunk.logging.HttpEventCollectorSender$4.onResponse(HttpEventCollectorSender.java:356)
    at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:141)
    at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Exception in thread "OkHttp Dispatcher" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gson.JsonParser.parseString(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/google/gson/JsonElement;
    at com.splunk.logging.HttpEventCollectorErrorHandler$ServerErrorException.<init>(HttpEventCollectorErrorHandler.java:56)
    at com.splunk.logging.HttpEventCollectorSender$3.completed(HttpEventCollectorSender.java:308)
    at com.splunk.logging.HttpEventCollectorSender$4.onResponse(HttpEventCollectorSender.java:356)
    at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:141)
    at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)to
```

Comment: The version of Gson that you are using isn’t compatible with the version of Splunk that you are using. What are their respective versions? If you are using Spring Boot, as the question’s tags suggest, knowing the Spring Boot version would also be useful as Spring Boot provides dependency management for Gson.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson - what makes you state that? how can a "version of JSON" affect whether Splunk can read it?

Comment: “Gson” wasn’t a typo. It’s a JSON processing library from Google: https://github.com/google/gson. The version in use here is binary incompatible with the version of Splunk.

Answer (score 0):

`Splunk` has `com.google.gson` as a dependency. The installation is not detailed in the question but the library is not on the path as detailed in the [manual](https://dev.splunk.com/enterprise/docs/devtools/java/sdk-java/gettingstartedsdkjava/installsdkjava/).

> gson-2.1.jar contains third-party tokenizers for parsing results for
> JSON output. Add this to your build path to display search results in
> JSON format using the ResultsReaderJson class.

`NoSuchMethodError` reports that the version found is too old for what is attempted. The dependency tree must be verified to locate which version is loaded first.

Comment: If Gson was absent, you’d get a `ClassNotFoundException` or `NoClassDefFoundError`. The `NoSuchMethodError` indicates that `com.google.gson.JsonParser` is already on the classpath and has been loaded but that the `parseString(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/google/gson/JsonElement` method is missing.

Comment: Without the dependency tree, sorting imports is unfeasible.. JsonParser method appeared in [1.3](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/JsonParser.html).

Comment: While `JsonParser` has existed since 1.3, the `parseString` method was added in [this commit](https://github.com/google/gson/commit/c5a3f21fbad3828deba1deb88168e1f76829f807) which means it's new in 2.8.6.